# Trouble with file paths in C# (home

Tags: c#

I'm trying to test this Program using a test.txt file in my Documents folder. I'm having trouble getting the paths right. can some one give me some ideas? its a homework assignment and I'm almost done with it!!

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program


{
    // declare constants to use in wind chill factor equation - no magic numbers
    const double EQUATION_NUMBER_ONE = 35.74;
    const double EQUATION_NUMBER_TWO = 0.6215;
    const double EQUATION_NUMBER_THREE = 35.75;
    const double EQUATION_NUMBER_FOUR = 0.4275;
    const double EQUATION_EXPONENT = 0.16;
    const int DEGREE_SYMBOL = 176;

    static void Main()
    {       

        // declare some variables for the main method
        string fileName = "";
        string line = "";
        double t = 0.0;
        double v = 0.0;
        double wchillf = 0.0;
        char degreeSymbol = (char)DEGREE_SYMBOL;


        string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
       (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "c:\\";


        // Give student Info and ask user for a file name.
        // we will read this file and use the info for our input.
        Console.WriteLine("Wind Chill Calculator Braught to you by Teancum");
        Console.WriteLine("for CS 1400 01X");
        Console.WriteLine("11/11/2012");
        Console.WriteLine("Project 8");
        Console.Write("Please enter the file name in your My Documents folder: ");
        fileName = Console.ReadLine();


        string path = environment + fileName;
        //we will create a new instance of the StreamReader class
        //as well find the file in the documents folder
        //this will read the Info and orginise it.
        StreamReader windChillinfo = new StreamReader(path);


        // start the do loop to keep readding the file untill there is no more information
        do
        {
            // read in a line and save it as a string variable
            line = windChillinfo.ReadLine();

            //this if is to make sure there is no invalid info for example if the file is empty.
            if (line != null)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split();
                t = double.Parse(values[0]);
                v = double.Parse(values[1]);

                //here we call the windchillmagic Method
                wchillf = WindChillMagic(t, v);

                //here will be the Results of the windchillmagic method 
                Console.WriteLine("\nFor a temperature {0:f2} F{1}", t, degreeSymbol);
                Console.WriteLine("\nand a wind speed of {0:f2}mph", v);
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe wind chill factor would be = {0:f2}{1}\n", wchillf, degreeSymbol);
            }
        } while (line != null);

        windChillinfo.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you for and keep Warm! Press enter to EXIT");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }//End Main()


    static double WindChillMagic(double t, double v)
    {
        double wci = 0.0;
        wci = EQUATION_NUMBER_ONE + (EQUATION_NUMBER_TWO * t) - (EQUATION_NUMBER_THREE * (Math.Pow(v, EQUATION_EXPONENT))) + (EQUATION_NUMBER_FOUR * t * (Math.Pow(v, EQUATION_EXPONENT)));
        return wci;
    }
}//End class Program
```

Comment: `string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
       (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "c:\\";` is very nonsensical...

Comment: Why are you adding C:\ after getting the personal folder? Using a debugger will help you understanding what's happening with your path

Comment: HAHA... Thank you!! It works "//" the C: path was bad form  THANK YOU!

Comment: Pls try to post the trouble some part of the code. Use debugger to test yourself first and understand the root of the problem..

Comment: You can use this to get the bin or relese folder path : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: Another tip is to use @"C:\" instead of "C:\\".  The @ when used with string literals tells it that backslashes are really backslashes, so that you don't need to escape them.  Pretty handy when working with paths with lots of \

Answer (score 3):

How about you do something along the lines of following:

```
String path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "filename.txt");

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false))
{
    sw.WriteLine("Hello, file.");
}
```

This worked for me - now I have the file "filename.txt" in my Documents folder, with text "Hello, file." inside.

---

Your version doesn't work as you're doing this:

```
string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
   (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "c:\\";
```

This means, if your personal folder was "C:\Users\Username\Documents", the `environment` string will now contain the value `C:\Users\Username\Documentsc:\", and after you combine it into the path with

```
fileName = Console.ReadLine();
string path = environment + fileName;
```

if you entered "test.txt", the `path` will now contain `C:\Users\Username\Documentsc:\test.txt`. You should **use a debugger** to find these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

This looks backwards:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath
       (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "c:\\";
```

If GetFolderPath returns "SomeFolder\SomeOtherFolder" then what you produced is "SomeFolder\SomeOtherFolderc:\"

If you put a breakpoint here and stepped pass the line and then mouse over the `environment` variable, you'd see this problem.

1) It is backwards.
2) You should probably use Path.Combine instead.

`string path = environment + fileName;`

Should probably use Path.Combine instead so a slash is added between.  What if `environment` doesn't end in a slash?  Then you'd get "C:\SomeFolder\SomeOtherFoldersomeUsersFilename"